# How to provide list of possible passwords to winrar?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, password-management, winrar

I have a list of possible passwords and bunch of rar files. As you suspect, I would like to open, unrar all those files using provided passwords but I don't know which password is related to which rar file.

Is there a possibility to open those rars in some elegant way?

Is there a possibility to load list of passwords into rar app and attempt every password on every file (until success of course)?

I would like to resolve it using rar app interface. I know how to do it by coding.

Comment: That functionality would surely just be showing how weak the program is, I very much doubt they'd include something like that within winRar itself.

Comment: @djsmiley2k it's 21st century, I am still optimistic :)

Comment: Short answer: No. You could write a script to try all possible password, but please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill That's unfortunate but as I expected... so I need to write a script. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Up to you .....

Answer (score -1):

You can automatically extract locked archives with JDownloader program. Possible passwords should be entered in Password List field located in Settings -> Archive Extractor. After that choose Extract Files function from Tools menu and select archives you want to extract. Program will automatically try entered passwords and extract archives if passwords are valid.